# Write web pages contents to text file

Tags: vb.net, save, text-files

I am used to VBA but I never tried VB .NET and I need to get the text from 2 web pages to a text file. This is the code I am using, but I am having problems! What changes do I have to do to make it work?

```
Public mIE As Object
Public arrText(1) As String
Public Const myFile As String = "C:\myTextFile.txt"

Public Sub Main()
    Dim arrURL(1) As String
    Dim i As Byte

    On Error Resume Next
    Kill (myFile)

    ' Define URL
    arrURL(0) = "http://URL1"
    arrURL(1) = "http://URL2"

    For i = 0 To 1
        'Spawn Internet Explorer
        mIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

        arrText(i) = openWebPage(arrURL(i))

        mIE.Quit()
        mIE.Close()
        mIE = Nothing
    Next

    Call saveToTextFile
End Sub

Public Function openWebPage(myURL As String) As String
    With mIE
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Height = 800
        .Height = 600
        .AddressBar = 0
        .StatusBar = 0
        .Toolbar = 0
        .Visible = True
        .navigate (myURL)
    End With

    openWebPage = mIE.document.body.innerText
End Function

Public Sub saveToTextFile()
    Dim oWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(myFile )
    Dim i As Byte

    For i = 0 To UBound(arrText)
        oWriter.WriteLine (arrText(i))
    Next

    oWriter.Close()
End Sub
```

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: What are the problems you are having?

Comment: The problem that I have is in the for loop of the main procedure. When i = 1 the  arrText(i) = openWebPage(arrURL(i)) is returning 'Nothing' . It should return the contents of the of 2nd URL page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have arguments that are not found, like 'fichSGA'.  They may be in code you did not provide.  You can add 'breakpoints' in Visual Studio and then stepping over them by hitting F10 on a standard keyboard.  Then generally you can hover over a variable or item and it shows it's value.  If it's not there that could be part of the problem.  Here is a super simple Console App in Vb.NET to print out a file using a StreamWriter.  In this example there is no error catching so just make sure you have the C:\Test folder existing.

```
Imports System.IO

 Public Sub WriteTextToFile(text As String, location As String)
    Using sw = New StreamWriter(location)
      sw.Write(text)
    End Using
  End Sub

  Sub Main()
    Dim someText = "I am just some text"
    Dim someMoreText = "I am more text"

    Dim combined = someText + Environment.NewLine + someMoreText

    WriteTextToFile(combined, "C:\Test\Test.txt")
  End Sub
```